# Modernizr not working second time I click (Umbraco css)

Tags: jquery, svg, umbraco, modernizr

I have a website, http://excellent-grib.com/ in Umbraco and the logo up left is loading perfectly as a .svg file. But when I click on any other link than "FORSIDE" (frontpage) then Modernizr will not change the image from .gif to .svg.

My JQuery function is:

```
$(document).ready(function (event) {    
    if (Modernizr.svg){
        $('#logo_image').attr('src', '/graphics/excellentSystems_logo.svg');
    }
});
```

Funny enough I have another script in my header with Modernizr,

```
<script>
    Modernizr.load('http://excellent-grib.com/css/enhanced.css');
    Modernizr.load('http://excellent-grib.com/css/responsive.css');
</script>
```

This is working fine.

Any help will be quite appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing the issue in chrome, perhaps it is a problem shown only in certain browsers - which one are you using?

That being said, I wouldn't do this the way you are doing it. Currently you are requesting the .gif, and then "upgrading" to the svg. Since you have modernizr in the head of your document, you can use the css classes it provides to use a background image, rather than the image file. Meaning the user only downloads one file, as well as completely avoiding this issue.

Secondly, you shouldn't use `Modernzr.load` without providing any tests. Since they are always loaded, and it is via javascript it is [killing your page performance](https://www.igvita.com/2014/05/20/script-injected-async-scripts-considered-harmful/). Just load them up in normal `<script>` tags :]